# Is there a more configurable alternative to Photoshop's Extrude filter?

Tags: photoshop-effects

I really like the Extrude filter (Filter > Stylize > Extrude), but it isn't very configurable so it tends to give similar results each time.

So I'm looking for an alternative method or plugin that can generate similar pseudo-3D effects, but allows more options for the shape of the extruded elements, such as pyramids, cylinders and blocks.

Comment: Photoshop Extended has 3D features built into it.

Comment: I had in mind the filter effect, which is already built-in in the Photoshop (filter->stylize-> extrude), not the 3D effects. There is a limitation to upload a screenshot in comment. So it's hard to show you what I mean.

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/50185/edit) to add images if necessary. Just click the [Edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/50185/edit) link above (or the links in this comment).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do it manually in Photoshop. **BUT**, if you have access to Illustrator you could use the 3d bevel effect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

YMMV